# Sink several Kafka topics to s3 under different paths

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, avro

With the release of Flink 1.4 the FlinkKafkaConsumer011 has the functionality to pass a regex in for topics to read— a rad feature btw. Now I’m wondering if there is a way for a single Flink application to sink each of those topics (Avro messages) using the BucketingSink to separate locations in  s3. For example:

```
s3://bucket/topic_1
s3://bucket/topic_2
s3://bucket/topic_3
.
.
.
s3://bucket/topic_n
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Check does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473343/unable-to-write-to-s3-using-s3-sink-using-streamexecutionenvironment-apache-fl

Answer (score 0):

If your root bucket is different and you "just" want a different path for each topic you can:

1. get the topic from the metadata and store it on your element when deserializing your messages from Kafka
2. pass it along on your elements through the full processing
3. provide a subclass of BasePathBucketer which redefines the getBucketPath method to return the path with topic by querying the topic in the passed element.